# Git: Interrogate a distant repo without creating a local copy

Tags: git

In a CGI script, I would like to get the common ancestor of two branches on a distant git repository (to know when two branches have been merged for the last time), but since it is a heavy one, I don't want my web server to have to manage a local copy just to answer that question.

Is there a way to do so with git?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Determining the common ancestor requires reading the commit objects, which must be available, so you must have a local repository.

If you have control over the server that hosts the remote repository, you could of course write a script that would find the common ancestor locally (to the remote host) and return the result. But that's out of the scope of Git.

Comment: Okay, well, think is kind of what I expected. Thank you for your answer! Maybe the simplest way would be to run the command through SSH to get the command ancestor log.